# Visual Studio - How to make sure all .cs files are included?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, csproj

My issue is the following:

Sometimes when I'm adding a new file to the a project, because of all the merges and shelving/unshelving, it's no longer included in the .csproj.

It's pretty hard to figure out that the file isn't included in a project, especially since it remains source controlled, so for the most part everything looks fine.

Is there a tool or an option in Visual Studio so that I can know if not **all .cs files are included in a project**?

Comment: use msbuild for manipulating .csproj file

Comment: Click Show All Files.

Comment: You can turn on "show all files" in VS.

Comment: After a merge you should still do a "Build All" and run the unit tests to ensure the merge itself didn't break anything. This should also point out any files that are now missing from the project after a merge.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2013, 
1. Select project
2. Press alt + p + o (Show all files)
3. Press * (open all in solution explorer).

Look if any files are not included